# How do I modify an object value in a cloned array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:

`const arrA = [{a: true}];`

And I create a copy of the array like so:

`const arrB = Array.from(arrA);`

But when I modify the value of the object in arrB, the value in arrA gets modified too.

```
arrB[0].a = false
// arrB = [{a:false}]
// arrA = [{a:false}] - gets modified also
```

How do I modify the object values in the cloned array without modifying the original array.

Comment: The question is then: How do I clone an object? Your array does not care about its contents, cloning an array does not clone the objects in it, it just creates a new array with references to those objects. Maybe try `const arrB = Array.from(arrA).map(o => Object.assign({},o));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.from` creates what is called a **shallow copy**. Shallow copy means you have 2 variables- `arrA` and `arrB` pointing at the *same array* in memory, so you change one it changes the other. With objects inside its even more complicated- cuz even if you manage to create different array in memory- it might still point on the same objects as the previous array, leading to again- one change the changes both.

The opposite is deep copy- creating a new array with new objects that hold the same data *values*, not references. There are a few methods for that, you can read more [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089), I recommend on `JSON.parse/stringify` as the easiest one:

```
const arrA = [{a: true}];
const arrB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrA));
```

This will give you what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arrA = [{a: true}];
const arrB = arrA.map(x => ({...x}))
arrB[0].a = false;
console.log(arrA)
console.log(arrB)
```

You can use `map` method to map your older array and create a deep copy of every object using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).